# Create a read-only file in C++

Tags: c++, file, mfc, readonly

I need save textual information using my VC++ MFC application in a file such that it will be read-only. 
So far, I have considered two alternatives, but I am not happy with either

1) I could save the file as a pdf. But the couple of pdf libraries I have looked at, both appear to have a steep learning curve.

2) Zip the file inside an archive, even password protect it. However, that still does not make it read-only. For zipping, I found this wonderful library - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win

Could you please suggest me a better way of doing it.

FWIW, I am on Visual Studio 2013, so I have C++11 available to me. Also, I have Boost linked into my code.

Comment: Even PDF files can be modified if one is motivated enough. I don't think you should aim to prevent others from editing your file -- consider digitally signing it instead, so you can detect such modifications and react appropriately.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, that's a great suggestion. Could you please suggest me an easy way of doing it in C++? I am familiar with the general idea because I know Git uses something like that to create the hashes

Comment: There are a lot of questions dealing with on Stack Overflow. A quick search revealed [Digital signature with CryptVerifySignature](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12713715/464709), which may be appropriate for you as a starting point.

Comment: It is entirely likely that you are trying to do exactly the wrong thing. "Read-only" means different things in different contexts. Why do you think you need a read-only text file? PDF makes no sense here. Any user can, instead of trying to alter your PDF, create an entirely new file and replace yours. Password-protected file makes no sense either. Password needs to be hidden somewhere. If you can hide a password you can hide the original file, no need to encrypt it. Besides an encrypted file is unreadable and you need unwritable.

Comment: @n.m., I am storing information to be used later, which will cause headache if modified in the meanwhile.

Comment: Millions of programs do that, and most don't bother with any sort of protection, despite all sorts of bad things that might happen when such file gets altered. If your information is so special it's worth special protection, it's worth *breaking* that protection. And a determined attacker will be able to break your protection, make no mistake about it. Conversely, if it's not worth breaking the protection, it's not worth protecting. You need *extraordinary* justification for your desire to protect the file. But all you are saying is "bad things will happen". Not convincing.

Comment: @n.m., the machine needs to be exposed to say 10 people, of whom only 4 will be given the password for the archive

Comment: If you give the users admin rights, any of them can discover the password. If you don't, you don't need any password or signature protection, just don't give them *permission* to change the file.

Comment: @n.m. How can admins discover password for a zip file if the password for the archive is not shared with them?

Comment: Passwords can be leaked intentionally, written down on a sticky note attached to a monitor, spied by lookin over one's shoulder, brute forced, stolen with a homemade keylogger and whatnot. Decrypted files can be trivially stolen. User identities and group memberships of non-admins by non-admins cannot. Your OS has a multi-user ability for a reason. If you want security, follow established security practices. Or ignore them and use whatever works for you, it just not likely to work for too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `boost::filesystem` to accomplish this with the following function:

`void permissions(const path& p, perms prms);`

a `path` can be constructed from a string, so no problem there. The hard part is the `perms` which is a sort of bit mask. You need to use `remove_perms` in that bitmask to signal that permissions should be removed.

The following code should work (untested):

```
using boost::filesystem::perms;
boost::filesystem::path myPath("foo.txt");
boost::filesystem::permissions(myPath, 
    perms::remove_perms|perms::owner_write|perms::others_write|perms::group_write);
```

[Boost Filesystem reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#permissions)

---

### Edit 9/8/2020

A note about deleting read-only files. In Linux, so long as someone has write-access to the immediate parent directory, they can remove the file (unless you take [extreme measures](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67508/how-do-i-make-a-file-not-modifiable)). In Windows, you will need to restore write access to the file in order to delete it.

I chose to *remove* permissions instead of set the permissions explicitly to read-only in the original answer because the Boost docs have a note about how only the write permissions do anything. Anecdotally, I can say that I've had success with `permissions(path, owner_read|others_read|group_read)` (In windows), but to be on the safe side we should follow the docs, I guess.

I'd also like to note that this entire answer is basically moot if you have C++17, because `std::filesystem` is available to you (the API is very much like Boost's).

Comment: That's not really useful. Most people are administrators on their Windows boxes so they can trivially change these permissions.

Comment: @n.m. In my case, yes, everyone is an admin, so I guess this won't work. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In this case (multiple admins on the same machine) absolutely nothing will work. Don't thank me for pointing that out, it's blindingly obvious. You have a security problem, not a programming problem. I suggest asking your question at http://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @n.m. Agreed. The question in my eyes was how to set the file permissions as read-only programmatically rather than secure a file such that no changes can ever be made to it, which is a much different question.

Comment: @AndyG, thanks for sharing, sorry for not being clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just do this:

```
ofstream out;
out.open("test.txt");
out.close();
//attrib [parameters] [file]
//+R -> readonly
//+H -> hidden
//+S -> system file (ultra hidden)
//There are more, type 'attrib /?' in cmd to find all of the options
system("attrib +R test.txt");
```

And that's it! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**

This only works on Windows, as it uses a direct console command.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code:

```
HANDLE  hFile = CreateFile(L"read_only_file.txt", GENERIC_ALL, 0, NULL, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);
```